# View all instance variables currently available? (Ruby)

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I have been asked to work on a large project (already half-done). One file I'm working on starts with this:

```
<div class="table-responsive">
  <table class="table">
    <% if @incidents.present? %>
      <br>
      <thead>
```

I didn't know @incidents existed, until I saw it referenced. It made me wonder—what other instance variables are available for me to use? How would I know?

Because this is a big project with many files interacting, I don't want to just look at the controller or something like that, **I want a way to log all instance variables available to me at a particular point in the code**.

Comment: Please search before asking

Comment: "Get all instance variables declared in class"—I don't have a class (well, it's hidden), I'm just at the very top of a view that starts to reference variables. @WesFoster I think your possible duplicate is correct, but I couldn't find it with my own search. Does that merit this question (others might be like me) or should I take it down?

Comment: You can remove it, or leave it and have it redirect to the other post. Either way, others with this problem can find the solution by running a quick search.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
@foo = 3
instance_variables # => [:@foo]
```